# Get the keys from JSON Array into a list without Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have an service that returns me an json object like the below

```
{
  "header": {},
  "title": {},
  "terms": {
     "data": {
        "list": [
          "string": 1,
          "string1": 2,
          "string2": 3
                ]
              }
           }
}
```

Now I need to get the keys of the list json array into a list. I have got the array into an object

```
    List<String> allTerms = new ArrayList<String>();
    String response = HttpRequest.get("http://myservice/get").body();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(response);
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

    JSONObject fieldObj = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("terms");
    JSONObject queryObj = (JSONObject)fieldObj.get("data");
    JSONArray termsArr = (JSONArray) queryObj.get("list");
    //iterate the termsarr and get the string,string1,string2 keys alone to allTerms list
```

Is there a more better way to do this? Im using [json-simple](https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) and [a custom http client](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request)

Comment: That doesn't seem like a properly formatted json

Comment: There's no such thing as "key of an array" in JSON

Answer (score 0):

By using basic for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<termsArr.length(); i++) {

     String[] arr = termsArr.getString(i).split("\"");
     allTerms.add(arr[1]);
    }
```